# Terraform Registry Service unreachable in Docker

Tags: docker, terraform

While running terraform inside a docker container, I am facing some issue which is causing me a lot of trouble.

I am simply running terraform init and getting following error.

```
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.12.24
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.12.13
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/bin/terraform", "init"}
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /root/.terraformrc
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init"}

Initializing the backend...
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: no config given or present on disk, so returning nil config
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend has not previously been initialized in this working directory
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "f8a611ca-c103-f9fd-aad6-c0c6e9484f34"
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using default local state only (no backend configuration, and no existing initialized backend)
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type <nil>
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/bin"
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/bin"
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [INFO] Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend <nil> does not support operations, so wrapping it in a local backend
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] backend/local: state manager for workspace "default" will:
 - read initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
 - write new snapshots to terraform.tfstate
 - create any backup at terraform.tfstate.backup
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: reading initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: snapshot file has nil snapshot, but that's okay
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: read nil snapshot
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/bin"

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] plugin requirements: "aws"=""
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [DEBUG] Service discovery for registry.terraform.io at https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
2020/12/05 17:59:44 [TRACE] HTTP client GET request to https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
2020/12/05 17:59:54 [DEBUG] Failed to request discovery document: Get https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Registry service unreachable.

This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.


Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates
```

I am unable to understand the issue, I have not mounted anything on the container.

Comment: Run this command from the container see it reaches the registry
"curl "https://registry.terraform.io/""

Comment: @AvihayTsayeg its coming 200 return code.